Does polarization of linearly polarized radiowave change on reflection
So, dear community, I have a dispute with a UAV instructor on the behavior of radiowaves reflected from the surfaces (here and further on please consider we`re talking about non-transparent matters like metal, wood or concrete).
In case of circular polarization it's clear it can rotate on reflection.
But for linear one things become obscure for me. A lot of sources state polarization changes on reflection in general, but don't specify it relates to all kinds or just to some variants.
Few say it does change, in extreme cases even rotating from vertical to horizontal not providing any references or proofs of that.
Could you please help to wrap my head around this and provide trustful materials explicitly proofing the answer for linear polarization.
Thank you in advance!

Consult the Fresnel equations. A good source is the classic textbook "Optics" by Hecht.

Generally speaking yes. Specifically, the so-called s- and p-polarizations reflect with different phases that depend on parameters such as refractive indices on the media and the angle of incidence/reflection. More specifically, if you want hard numbers check Fresnel equations.
NB. Although in general reflected light is elliptically polarized, there are two special cases where linearly polarized light remains linear: s- and p-polarizations (electric field polarized orthogonal and parallel to the plane of incidence respectively).

Using two mirrors one can change a vertically polarized laser beam propagating parallel to the ground into a horizontally polarized laser beam propagating parallel to the ground. Good spectroscopists always know their polarizations.

@Jon Custer I would rather say decent spectroscopists. But I hear you. By today's standards just being responsible is enough to be viewed as "good".

It's a little confusing when you say "surfaces"..does that mean a single bounce considered over different surfaces (flat, or not), or a multi-bound single return from a so-called scene?
The former is undergrad electromagnetics.
The latter is a research field:
Polarization is huge in space borne radar remote sensing of complex features on the Earth's surface, One could write a book on it.
See
Canada:
https://natural-resources.canada.ca/maps-tools-and-publications/satellite-imagery-elevation-data-and-air-photos/tutorial-fundamentals-remote-sensing/microwave-remote-sensing/radar-polarimetry/9275
NASA:
https://nisar.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/get-to-know-sar/polarimetry/
IEEE (a book!):
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/book/5201456
UVA (anyone familiar?):
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349285211_Use_Of_Linear-Polarization_Doppler_Radar_System_to_Detect_Falls_Results_From_a_Simulated_Living_Environment
Oh, and it's a "thing" in weather, where the aerodynamic drag on a rain drop is size dependent so that the easy-to-solve for spherical drop equations
(via spherical Bessel functions) turn into ellipsoidal special functions..., anyway, the semi-major axises can be estimated by comparing the ratio of literally vertical vs horizontal returns, while the total drop density comes from the sum: https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/14/15/3706
given much more accurate results compared with unpolarized/uni-polar scattering.
